# How to personlized search results based on user profile properties [managed metadata]

Tags: search, managed-metadata, user-profile-property, managed-property

I am looking to personalize search result based on what is stored in user profile properties. I have list of user profiles properties connected to the managed metadata. Any pointers would be appreciated?

I am using the search web parts to display search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [query variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123(v=office.15).aspx) to configure queries for search results.

In your case, try using query variables of User Profile properties something like `{User.<property>}`.

**For example**, you might be interested in showing all the pages tagged with certain term, and that term should match user profile property. Hence, resulting query would be:

```
{User.Country} = {Page.Country}
```

Happy SharePointing!